# Ajuda! Cookies e javascript para criação de programa de Afiliado

Tags: javascript, cookies

preciso criar um programa de afiliado, onde todo afiliado cadastrado recebera um link único com um link relacionado com a ID dele na DB, por exemplo:

exemplo.com/afiliadoid?4312123

Preciso criar um cookies com validade de 30 dias, que quando o usuário que acessar o site por sua primeira vez através do link do afiliado, ficara salvo e posteriormente caso venha a realizar o preenchimento de um formulário, este formulário capture em um campo oculto o ID do afiliado.

Como posso fazer isto? Obrigado

Comment: De uma lida: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode fazer isso direto no Javascript, quando renderizar o documento, 
pegue a hash do link, e salve o coockie.

```
var url = "exemplo.com/afiliadoid?4312123";
var parametrosDaUrl = url.split("?")[1]; (4312123)

setcookie("CookieAfiliado", parametrosDaUrl, 30);
```

Depois aplique a logica para obtenção.
A lógica de aplicação posterior a 30 dias você vai ter que analisar, porque ela irá se ronavar quando expirar.
Tem N formas de fazer, eu acabaria indo para outro lado, armazenado dados via banco de dados, controlando tempo de validade no back-end, fornecendo usuário e senha.